# check if rel=group exists for fancybox using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, concrete5

I have the following code in my page:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Fancy LightBox
    $("a[rel=group]").fancybox({
        'transitionIn'      : 'elastic',
        'changeFade'        : 'fast',
        'transitionOut'     : 'elastic',
        'titlePosition'     : 'over',
        'overlayOpacity'    : '0.6',
        'showCloseButton'   : false,
        'overlayColor'      : '#000000',
        'titleFormat'       : function(title, currentOpts) {
                return '<span id="fancybox-title-over">'+ (title.length ? ' &nbsp; ' + title : '') + '</span>';
            }
    });

});
</script>
```

But when there is not an element with `rel=group` it crashes my Concrete5 dashboard panel. Is there a way to check if the element with `rel=group` exists and if it does not, DONT fire the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
if($('a[rel="group"]').length > 0)
{
    $('a[rel="group"]').fancybox({
```

Comment: Thank you.. It works! Is this the fastest efficient way to check?